# Custom Event/Interrupt Handling in C++

Tags: events, opencv, user-interface

Is there any general-purpose programming equivalent of low-level interrupts in microcontrollers/embedded systems?

I am vaguely familiar with the concept of events (mouse events and the like) which seems similar but not general enough. 
Is there a mechanism (native or otherwise), specifically in C/C++, to handle custom events, that is, events whose triggering is decided by a user-defined condition like say, when the mouse-pointer moves into a particular region when a particular user action occurs?

To provide some context, I am working on an OpenCV based interactive project where I would like to trigger specific actions when the user points to a particular place on the screen.

It seems to be a particular waste of computation to check if the pointer is currently at so and so location on the screen in each iteration of the video stream and I would like to automate function calls based on a pre-defined condition.

Or is there any other(more efficient) mechanism by which I could improve this procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no interrupt programming in C/C++ as in microP or microC .
2. If your screen is touch screen then you try to get hold of the SDK of your operating system or API of your OS to get notified when a touch happens. (The OS internally maintains an interrupt table for touch or key pad press or mouse movement. We can program the logic which we want to execute on such an event, nothing more than that..).
3. If its not touch then you have to monitor the position of the user with a sensor, usually a camera (a web cam). For that you have to check each frame of the camera to decide the position of the user.
   **EDIT :**
4. What you mentioned is the correct way.Its better to check each frame or else the response of your system will be sluggish. You can assign a counter to 1 and increase it with each frame and reset it on reaching any desired value. This is almost equivalent to a infinite loop.
5. Or you can accept some key from the keyboard to break out the loop (OpenCV has such functions)
6. A little more advanced approach is to grab frames from the camera in a different thread than the main thread of your executing program. So all you need to do is to start and stop that thread.

Comment: I am programming for a desktop so (2) doesn't apply. So, I'll have to poll each frame for all conditions? Or is there any alternative by which I could reduce the number of checks per frame?

Comment: If you use a camera then ideally you have to...however since camera is 20 - 30 fps so you are sampling the hand movement every 50 - 30 ms..generally human hand doesn't move so fast..so you can sample every 500ms or each second...so check after an interval of 20 to 15 frames...

Comment: On a related topic, how do you monitor the number of frames which has elapsed? I mean, if you sample at a fairly fast rate, at some point the variable holding the number of frames would overflow and would require resetting. Is this the usual procedure or is there a better way out? I am new to this so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: ha ha...every one was new to something else or the other at some point of time...so no forgive n stuff...check edit of my answer..